# Ribbon background color cannot be set

Tags: winapi

To change the ribbon colors, from [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/windowsribbon/ribbon-color):

```
CComPtr<IPropertyStore> spPropertyStore;

// _spFramework is a pointer to the IUIFramework interface that is assigned 
// when the Ribbon is initialized.
if (SUCCEEDED(_spFramework->QueryInterface(&spPropertyStore)))
{
  PROPVARIANT propvarBackground;
  PROPVARIANT propvarHighlight;
  PROPVARIANT propvarText;

  // UI_HSBCOLOR is a type defined in UIRibbon.h that is composed of 
  // three component values: hue, saturation and brightness, respectively.
  UI_HSBCOLOR BackgroundColor = UI_HSB(0x14, 0x38, 0x54);
  UI_HSBCOLOR HighlightColor = UI_HSB(0x00, 0x36, 0x87);
  UI_HSBCOLOR TextColor = UI_HSB(0x2B, 0xD6, 0x00);

  InitPropVariantFromUInt32(BackgroundColor, &propvarBackground);
  InitPropVariantFromUInt32(HighlightColor, &propvarHighlight);
  InitPropVariantFromUInt32(TextColor, &propvarText);

  spPropertyStore->SetValue(UI_PKEY_GlobalBackgroundColor, propvarBackground);
  spPropertyStore->SetValue(UI_PKEY_GlobalTextColor, propvarText);

  spPropertyStore->Commit();
}
```

This does not work in Windows 10, background color is left unchanged. It works in Windows 7. Only the "File" is changed.

[image]

Any options?

Comment: I test with [Windows Ribbon: SimpleRibbon](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=9620) on Windows 10, change `hue` from `0x14` to `0xAA` cause `File tab` background color change from blue to green. Can you have a try? And show snapshots of what you get and what you expect.

Comment: Only the "File" bg color is changed. I want a clear black background in all the ribbon.